# Foreign keys not populated

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So I've been having this weird problem where my foreign keys sometimes have values and when i come back to it they're null again.

I've double check the syntax and the relationship but they're just not giving me values.

This is the code that had it working but now now the foreign keys all display null.
The parent tables are populated primary keys and a distinct set of values that correlate to data in my_contacts. I've still left the columns in my_contacts with the original data that that these parent tables are supposed to replace. I'm thinking there should be some code to tell it to look at the profession column in my_contacts and then give prof_id a value the corresponds with the prof_id table but it was doing this automatically before and then stopped. The only thing I did was inspect another table with 'SELECT *'
Any help will be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts

ADD COLUMN prof_id INT DEFAULT NULL,

ADD COLUMN  zip_code INT DEFAULT NULL,

ADD COLUMN status_id INT DEFAULT NULL,

ADD CONSTRAINT fk_prof_my_contacts 
  FOREIGN KEY (prof_id) 
  REFERENCES profession (prof_id),

ADD CONSTRAINT fk_status_my_contacts 
    FOREIGN KEY (status_id) 
    REFERENCES status (status_id),

ADD CONSTRAINT fk_zip_my_contacts 
  FOREIGN KEY (zip_code) 
  REFERENCES zip_code (zip_code);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is wrong.

There is no magic that populates the foreign key columns.

When those columns were added, they were assigned NULL value (because of the DEFAULT NULL clause of the column definitions.)

With InnoDB, a foreign key constraint *disallows* the assignment of invalid values to the foreign key column.  The foreign key constraint on `prof_id` (in `my_contacts` table) says that any value assigned to that column *must* appear as a value in the `prof_id` column of at least one row in the `profession` table.

The foreign key (as defined as shown in the question), defaults to `ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION`.

And the default `NO ACTION` is equivalent to specifying `RESTRICT`. That means that if there are any rows in `my_contacts` table with values of `prof_id` that reference a row in `profession` table, then an attempt to DELETE the referenced row from the `profession` table will cause an error. Also, any attempt to change to the value of the `prof_id` column of the referenced row in the `profession` will cause an error. Those actions would violate the rules enforced by the foreign key constraint.

---

The relationship between rows is established by storing a common value in the `prof_id` column of the two tables. Storing a non-null value in the `prof_id` column is what relates the row in `my_contacts` to a row in `profession`.

The foreign key constraint prevents invalid values from being assigned, and prevents changes to rows in the parent `profession` table that would cause established relationships to be broken.

The foreign key constraint does *not* cause any automatic assignment of values to  replace NULL values in the `prof_id` column.

Comment: so the DEFAULT NULL i put in i was just trying. i used a show create table for another table where it did have values in the prof_id column.

Comment: I'm still confused 
my_contacts was created first. it had a professions column. later i created a professions table with a primary key (prof_id) and a professions column. i pulled all the professions from the professions column in my_contacts and into the profession column in the professions table. the auto_incement prof_id gave numbers to all the profession.
i then added prof_id as a foreign key column in my_contacts and at a stage it worked and show values that related to the persons profession ones generated in the professions table. 
i can't understand why it would stop working

Comment: @EugeneHeynike: it sounds like what you did worked as expected, up to adding `prof_id` column to my_contacts. All rows would have `prof_id` col set to NULL. To get `prof_id` col populated on existing rows, that would require an `UPDATE` statement. Nothing shown or described here would have caused values to be automatically assigned to `prof_id` column. (There's potential for BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers to assign values, but that is totally independent of foreign key constraints.) If we are thinking foreign key constraints caused the foreign key column to be populated, our thinking is wrong.

Comment: oh ok thanks so much. it's making a bit more sense now. spoke to the lecturer and he was like 'nah we just punched in the values manually' i have two versions of the same table so what i saw was probably just the other table where we just punched in values.

Comment: i'm sure i could use a join to populate the prof_id on my_contacts with the right values right?